# significance of "trainable" and "training" flag in tf.layers.batch_normalization

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

What is the significance of "trainable" and "training" flag in tf.layers.batch_normalization? How are these two different during training and prediction?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The batch norm has two phases:**

```
1. Training:
   -  Normalize layer activations using `moving_avg`, `moving_var`, `beta` and `gamma` 
     (`training`* should be `True`.)
   -  update the `moving_avg` and `moving_var` statistics. 
     (`trainable` should be `True`)
2. Inference:
   -  Normalize layer activations using `beta` and `gamma`.
      (`training` should be `False`)
```

**Example code to illustrate few cases:**

```
#random image
img = np.random.randint(0,10,(2,2,4)).astype(np.float32)

# batch norm params initialized
beta = np.ones((4)).astype(np.float32)*1 # all ones 
gamma = np.ones((4)).astype(np.float32)*2 # all twos
moving_mean = np.zeros((4)).astype(np.float32) # all zeros
moving_var = np.ones((4)).astype(np.float32) # all ones

#Placeholders for input image
_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1,2,2,4), name='input')

#batch Norm
out = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
       _input,
       beta_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(beta),
       gamma_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(gamma),
       moving_mean_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(moving_mean),
       moving_variance_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(moving_var),
       training=False, trainable=False)


update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

 ## 2. Run the graph in a session 

 with tf.Session() as sess:

    # init the variables   
    sess.run(init_op)

    for i in range(2):
        ops, o = sess.run([update_ops, out], feed_dict={_input: np.expand_dims(img, 0)})
        print('beta', sess.run('batch_normalization/beta:0'))
        print('gamma', sess.run('batch_normalization/gamma:0'))
        print('moving_avg',sess.run('batch_normalization/moving_mean:0'))
        print('moving_variance',sess.run('batch_normalization/moving_variance:0'))
        print('out', np.round(o))
        print('')
```

*When `training=False` and `trainable=False`:*

```
  img = [[[4., 5., 9., 0.]...
  out = [[ 9. 11. 19.  1.]... 
  The activation is scaled/shifted using gamma and beta.
```

*When `training=True` and `trainable=False`:*

```
  out = [[ 2.  2.  3. -1.] ...
  The activation is normalized using `moving_avg`, `moving_var`, `gamma` and `beta`. 
  The averages are not updated.
```

*When `traning=True` and `trainable=True`:*

```
  The out is same as above, but the `moving_avg` and `moving_var` gets updated to new values.

  moving_avg [0.03249997 0.03499997 0.06499994 0.02749997]
  moving_variance [1.0791667 1.1266665 1.0999999 1.0925]
```

Comment: Thank you @vijay m

Comment: During inference, shouldn't the activation be normalized with the moving average and variance "learnt" from the training ?

Answer (score 5):

This is quite complicated.
And in TF 2.0 the behavior is changed, see this:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/095272a4dd259e8acd3bc18e9eb5225e7a4d7476/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/normalization_v2.py#L26

> **About setting `layer.trainable = False` on a `BatchNormalization` layer:**
>
> The meaning of setting `layer.trainable = False` is to freeze the
>   layer,   i.e. its internal state will not change during training:
>   its trainable weights will not be updated   during `fit()` or
>   `train_on_batch()`, and its state updates will not be run.   Usually,
>   this does not necessarily mean that the layer is run in inference
>   mode (which is normally controlled by the `training` argument that can
>   be passed when calling a layer). "Frozen state" and "inference mode"
>   are two separate concepts.
>
> However, in the case of the `BatchNormalization` layer, **setting
>
>   `trainable = False` on the layer means that the layer will be
>
>   subsequently run in inference mode** (meaning that it will use   the
>   moving mean and the moving variance to normalize the current batch,
>   rather than using the mean and variance of the current batch).   This
>   behavior has been introduced in TensorFlow 2.0, in order   to enable
>   `layer.trainable = False` to produce the most commonly   expected
>   behavior in the convnet fine-tuning use case.   Note that:
>
> - This behavior only occurs as of TensorFlow 2.0. In 1.*,   setting `layer.trainable = False` would freeze the layer but would   not
>     switch it to inference mode.
> - Setting `trainable` on an model containing other layers will   recursively set the `trainable` value of all inner layers.
> - If the value of the `trainable`   attribute is changed after calling `compile()` on a model,   the new value doesn't take effect for this
>     model   until `compile()` is called again.

Answer (score 3):

`training` controls whether to use the training-mode batchnorm (which uses statistics from this minibatch) or inference-mode batchnorm (which uses averaged statistics across the training data). `trainable` controls whether the variables created inside the batchnorm process are themselves trainable.